# After Uploading PNG image without background gets black background in Laravel. Please check

Tags: php, image, png

```
 private function processImageUpload($image,$image_name){
        //using image png function to change any image from jpeg to png and store to public folder
        $img  = imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image)), config('app.LOGO_MEDIA_PATH').'/'.$image_name.'.png');

        /*
       * TODO : change the image replacing functionality
       * from static name to upload to uploads folder
       * and get URL form settings table
       */

        $url = "/front/common/img/".$image_name.'.png';
        return $url;
    }
```

I enable the imagick extension in php.ini file but didn't happen anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution..Just need to add case with the image type. In this we can't convert png to png.

```
private function processImageUpload($image,$image_name){
    if($image->getMimeType() !== "image/png"){
        //using image png function to change any image from jpeg to png and store to public folder
        $img  = imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image)), config('app.LOGO_MEDIA_PATH').'/'.$image_name.'.png');
    }else{
        $image->move(config('app.LOGO_MEDIA_PATH'), $image_name.'.png');
    }

    /*
    * TODO : change the image replacing functionality
    * from static name to upload to uploads folder
    * and get URL form settings table
    */
    
    $url = "/front/common/img/".$image_name.'.png';
    return $url;
}
```